# Android Loading ListView from another Thread

Tags: android, android-listview

Please explain me why this code does not work?(I need to call the **lv.setAdapter (adapterA)** in the **onClick()**. It is necessary to change the adapters). It works if you run code on the main thread, but I need to load data in another Thread. I would be grateful for any ideas. Thank you.

```
package com.example.examplelist;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ActivityElemsExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ArrayList<Elem> myList;
    Button btn;
    ListView lv;
    AdapterA adapterA;
    AdapterB adapterB;
    boolean running = false;
    Thread thread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_loading);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);

        myList = new ArrayList<Elem>();
        adapterA = new AdapterA(this, myList);
        adapterB = new AdapterB(this, myList);
    }

    public void onClick(View button){
        if(!running){
            running = true;
            Log.d("MyLogs", "LOADING");

            /*
            if(...){
                lv.setAdapter(adapterA);
            }
            else{
                lv.setAdapter(adapterB);
            }
            */

            lv.setAdapter(adapterA);

            thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                myList.clear();

                for(int i=0; i < 3000; i++){
                    myList.add(new Elem(i, System.currentTimeMillis(), "Elem "+i));
                }
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(thread != null){
            while(true){
                try{
                    thread.join();
                    break;
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
        }
    }

    public Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            /*
             if(...){

             }
             else{

             }
             */

            adapterA.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            adapterA.notifyDataSetChanged();

            running = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.examplelist, PID:553
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its contentges ...
```

Comment: Consider Async Tasks. And use the onPostExecute method to update your UI.

Comment: Doomsknight, I think that this will not solve the problem. The problem comes when I call lv.setAdapter (adapterA) in the onClick (). But it is necessary for me to change adapters.

Comment: It would if you do it properly, I can guarantee it. As it's exactly what I do. You can call `AsyncTask`s from `onClick`. And it runs on a separate thread, but posts back on the UI thread at the end..

Comment: It worked! I filled ListView in another thread, then the main thread did call lv.setAdapter (adapterA). Also use AsyncTask. You were right. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped :) I assume you mean, you populated the array in the thread. Post your solution, and mark it as the correct answer, to help others in the future

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
package com.example.examplelist;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ActivityElemsExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ArrayList<Elem> myList;
    Button btn;
    ListView lv;
    AdapterA adapterA;
    AdapterB adapterB;
    boolean running = false;
    Thread thread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_loading);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);

        myList = new ArrayList<Elem>();

        adapterA = new AdapterA(this, myList);
        adapterB = new AdapterB(this, myList);

    }

    public void onClick(View button){
        if(!running){
            running = true;
            Log.d("MyLogs", "LOADING");

            thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                myList.clear();

                for(int i=0; i < 3000; i++){
                    myList.add(new Elem(i, System.currentTimeMillis(), "Elem "+i));
                }
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(thread != null){
            while(true){
                try{
                    thread.join();
                    break;
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
        }
    }

    public Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

            lv.setAdapter(adapterA);

            running = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run that piece of code on the UI thread from your background thread. Any work that will modify the UI such as the list needs to be on the UI thread. You can use the runOnUiThread method of an activity.

```
 MyActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // UI work here
       }
    });
```

You can also put all your items in a List on the background thread then update the adapter after you have all the items in your list.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are modifying the data of the adapter while showing it. You should make a copy of your data before adding more items, then replace the data in your adapter and notify.

Comment: Thank you. I understood this problem.